# Method reference and boolean

Tags: java, java-8

So I have been having a go with using the method reference in Java 8 (Object::Method). What I am attempting to do, which I have done before but have forgotten (last time I used this method reference was about 4 months ago), is find the amount of players that != online using the Method Reference.

```
public static Set<Friend> getOnlineFriends(UUID playerUUID)
{
    Set<Friend> friends = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ZMFriends.getFriends(playerUUID)));

    return friends.stream().filter(Friend::isOnline).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

public static Set<Friend> getOfflineFriends(UUID playerUUID)
{
    Set<Friend> friends = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ZMFriends.getFriends(playerUUID)));

    return friends.stream().filter(Friend::isOnline).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

As you can see I managed to so it when the player (friend) is online but I cannot figure out how to filter though the Set and collect the offline players. I'm missing something obvious, but what is it?!?!

Thanks,
Duke.

Comment: It's called method reference, not scope operator.

Comment: @Eran, oh dear. Apologises on my part, thinking about two things at once and accidentally put down the wrong thing! Thanks for picking me up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can think of:

`friends.stream().filter(i -> !i.isOnline()).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

But I guess that's not what you want, since it's not using a `method reference`. So maybe something like this:

```java
public static <T> Predicate<T> negation(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return predicate.negate();
}
...
friends.stream().filter(negation(Friend::isOnline)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Or `friends.stream().filter(((Predicate<Friend>)Friend::isOnline).negate()).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Answer (score 2):

In you code

```
public static Set<Friend> getOnlineFriends(UUID playerUUID)
{
    Set<Friend> friends = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ZMFriends.getFriends(playerUUID)));

    return friends.stream().filter(Friend::isOnline).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

you are creating a `List` view to the array returned by `ZMFriends.getFriends(playerUUID)`, copy its contents to a `HashSet`, just to call `stream()` on it.

That’s a waste of resources, as the source type is irrelevant to the subsequent stream operation. You don’t need to have a `Set` source to get a `Set` result. So you can implement your operation simply as

```
public static Set<Friend> getOnlineFriends(UUID playerUUID)
{
    return Arrays.stream(ZMFriends.getFriends(playerUUID))
                 .filter(Friend::isOnline).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Further, you should consider whether you really need both, `getOnlineFriends` and `getOfflineFriends` in your actual implementation. Creating utility methods in advance, just because you *might* need them, rarely pays off. See also “[You aren’t gonna need it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)”.

But *if* you really need both operations, it’s still an unnecessary code duplication. Just consider:

```
public static Set<Friend> getFriends(UUID playerUUID, boolean online)
{
    return Arrays.stream(ZMFriends.getFriends(playerUUID))
                 .filter(f -> f.isOnline()==online).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

solving both tasks. It still wastes resource, if the application really needs both `Set`s, as the application still has to perform the same operation twice to get both `Set`s. Consider:

```
public static Map<Boolean,Set<Friend>> getOnlineFriends(UUID playerUUID)
{
    return Arrays.stream(ZMFriends.getFriends(playerUUID))
                 .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Friend::isOnline, Collectors.toSet()));
}
```

This provides you *both* `Set`s at once, the online friends being associated to `true`, the offline friends being associated to `false`.